# What does kernel_constraint=max_norm(3) do?

Tags: optimization, computer-vision, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

In one of the tutorials I am working on  (link given below), the author outlines the baseline neural network structure as:

Convolutional input layer, 32 feature maps with a size of 3×3, a rectifier activation function and a weight constraint of max norm set to 3.

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 32, 32), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
```

What does weight constraint of max norm mean and do to the Conv layer? (We are using Keras.)

https://machinelearningmastery.com/object-recognition-convolutional-neural-networks-keras-deep-learning-library/

Thank you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**What does a weight constraint of `max_norm`do?**

`maxnorm(m)` will, if the L2-Norm of your weights exceeds `m`, scale your whole weight matrix by a factor that reduces the norm to `m`.
As you can find in the [keras code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/constraints.py) in `class MaxNorm(Constraint)`:

Now source code in the [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/constraints.py).

```
def __call__(self, w):
    norms = K.sqrt(K.sum(K.square(w), axis=self.axis, keepdims=True))
    desired = K.clip(norms, 0, self.max_value)
    w *= (desired / (K.epsilon() + norms))
    return w
```

Aditionally, `maxnorm` has an `axis` argument, along which the norm is calculated. In your example you don't specify an axis, thus the norm is calculated over the whole weight matrix. If for example, you want to constrain the norm of every convolutional filter, assuming that you are using `tf` dimension ordering, the weight matrix will have the shape `(rows, cols, input_depth, output_depth)`. Calculating the norm over `axis = [0, 1, 2]` will constrain each filter to the given norm.

**Why to do it?**

Constraining the weight matrix directly is another kind of regularization. If you use a simple L2 regularization term you penalize high weights with your loss function. With this constraint, you regularize directly.
As also linked in the `keras` code, this seems to work especially well in combination with a `dropout`layer. More more info see chapter 5.1 in [this paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ersalakhu/papers/srivastava14a.pdf)

Comment: Great explanation! Shouldn't it be "Calculating the norm over `axis = [0, 1]` will constrain each filter to the given norm" though?

Comment: It depends on what you plan to do. Using a convolutional layer with channels last dimension ordering, `axis = [0, 1, 2]` normalizes each convolutional filter, as `[:, : , :, i]` of the weigh matrix is the i-th filter. Using only `[0, 1]` constraints the filter weights of each plane, for example in the first layer the weights for the R, G and B channel are then normalized separately.

Comment: Got it. I understood "filter" as a single convolution matrix (what you refer to as "plane"), hence the confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give me a hint of how to apply a constraint only to a part of the weight matrix? For instance, only to the column odd column vectors w_ij  using keras?

Comment: @Cecilia. If the implementation is still the same, I think this can't be done. You would have to implement your own version where you compute the norm differently

Comment: @McLawrence the authors used max_norm constraint in the link you provided , also staong the C constant is a hyper-parameter to tune with validation set. Could you name a number for C constant that never hurts just as `relu` for activation?

Comment: answering the above question comment myself, dropout [paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a/srivastava14a.pdf)'s appendix A.3 states that  constant c ranges from 3 to 4.